# Image duplicated in media gallery

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

**Magento 2.4.6-p3**

I am almost sure that this is a setting, but at the moment, I am trying to figure out how to solve this. I have got a product that has one image:
[image]

On the product page, that exact image is shown twice in the media gallery.
[image]

I remember times with Magento 1 when an image could be excluded from the media gallery, but I can not find that setting in Magento 2.

How do I solve this?

Thanks!